# Group string in chunks of n characters and apply replace

Tags: javascript

This code takes "AK345KJ" and tries to get back ["A K 3", "4 5 K", "J"] but the browser is giving undefined in all items of the array.  Not sure why. Thanks

```
x = "AK345KJ"
x.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(function(item) {item.replace(""," "); console.log(item)})
```

Comment: No undefineds here https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2LjLoe7r/

Comment: @j08691: indeed, same here: http://prntscr.com/b391yz . Any change to see the entire source code? perhaps the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: Note that `replace` doesn't change the original string. It returns a new string. Also if you want to create a new array using the `map` method, you should return a value in the callback.

Comment: @briosheje it is all there. run in the browser console. no extra code.

Comment: @FredJ. can you please provide us a screenshot or the original html + js layout? if it logging undefined, the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Your `function(item){ ... } ` function implicitly returns `undefined` (since it has not `return` statement, so your resulting array fills up with `undefined` values. I assume you are actually storing and logging the result of the `map` call somewhere not shown here.

Comment: @Vohuman well, `x.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(function(item) {console.log(item.replace(""," "))})` still gives the same results

Comment: Do you mean you get an array of `undefined` values? Missing `return` statement in the callback is the reason.

Comment: And do not use a method/feature blindfolded. At first read  how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map` should return and adding spaces is done slightly differently.

You probably want something like this:

```
x.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(function(item) {return item.split('').join(' ');})
// ["A K 3", "4 5 K", "J"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using match()** :

```
var a = "AK345KJ"
var b = a.match(/(.{1,3})/g);
alert(b);
```

Snippet:

```js
var a = "AK345KJ";
var res = "";

//to split by fixed width of 3
var b = a.match(/(.{1,3})/g);
//alert(b);

//to add spaces
for (ab in b) {
  res = res + (b[ab].split('').join(' ')) + ", ";
}

//remove trailing ',' while alert
alert(res.substring(0, res.length - 2));
```

**Using the map function** (as shown in Uzbekjon's answer),
This whole think can be reduced to two lines :

```
var a = "AK345KJ"
alert(a.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(function(item) {return item.split('').join(' ');}));
```

Snippet :

```js
var a = "AK345KJ"
alert(a.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(function(item) {return item.split('').join(' ');}));
```